# selecting top 1 value for a group in sql with a where function <=2

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I am trying to create a new table with a new variable (y0) where the values are populated from an existing variable (EP) from table TabEP. The values in y0 will be the closest number greater than or equal to (>=) a specified value (2).

This is a mock up of table TabEP of values EP I currently have:

```
ID  EP  
_   _   
A | 1  
A | 2     
A | 3  
B | 1  
B | 2.2  
B | 3  
C | 1  
C | 2.3  
C | 3
```

What I want to have is my new table (#EP1) to read like this:

```
ID  Y0  
_   _   
A | 2     
B | 2.2  
C | 2.3
```

This is my sample code that I have been messing around with:

```
select * into #EP1
from
(select distinct
        id,
        (select top 1 EP from #TabEP where EP >=2 order by EP desc) as  'y0'
 from TabEP) EP1
```

What this ends up selecting is:

```
ID  Y0  
_   _   
A | 2     
B | 2  
C | 2
```

Comment: Sorry didn't add at the end

from TabEP) EP1

Comment: `EP <= 0.01` , Is this a typo? Shouldn't it be `>=` ? And do you mean closest but **smaller** then 3?

Comment: Sorry Yes that was a Typo, I was trying to reduce the real script down a bit and forgot to change the value.

Yes it would be smaller than, and the value should be 2

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make sense.  You explicitly state:  "The values in y0 will be the closes number lesser than or equal to (<=) a specified value (2)."  Yet, the values are greater than 2.

Comment: Gordon, Sorry changed the operators to make more sense with the question.

In my actual code I have to do this both for greater than and less than

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this works out:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(EP) Y0
FROM TabEP 
WHERE EP < 3
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Hi,

I receive this message 

"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"

Comment: @user3777003, the select statement above can never return that  error message. Line 26? Of 4 rows...

Comment: Lol. Now I want to know the DBMS you are using

Comment: Sorry saw my error.

 My only question is, my value could be 3 or it could be 2.9999. If I cannot put the '<=' in, I would be getting drastically different numbers for each id

Comment: Chaos Legion,

I am Using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Why don't you put <= instead of < in the above query?

Comment: By the way, my answer is giving the expected results as given in the question. Can you explain with an example where it doesn't?

Comment: Chaos,

I have changed it, I was getting the "subquery expression error" from before so I assumed I couldn't add the "=" operator.

Now it is just returning every instances of EP as Y0 and not querying out the values by ID

Comment: I don't think it's the sub-query but how you are using the sub-query, that is creating you the issue. Can you please share the exact query?

Comment: Chaos, Thanks a bunch for your help!

I had a small conversion error which I changed in my code. Thanks!

Comment: So, can you please mark my answer correct or upvote? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into EP1 (ID, Y0)
  select ID, min(EP) as Y0
  from TabEP
  where EP >= 2
  group by ID;
```

EP1:

```
| ID |  Y0 |
|----|-----|
|  A |   2 |
|  B | 2.2 |
|  C | 2.3 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9bef8d/1)